# Adding contents of text files to a hash set

Tags: java, hashset

I'm trying to create a dictionary using a HashSet by reading in text files. This works, but every time i read in a new text file, the contents of the HashSet from the previous text file is overridden. What i want is to append new instances of strings in variating text files to the HashSet, to create said dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    try {
    Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File("Test2.txt"));

    Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();

    while (textFile.hasNext()) {
        dictionary.add(textFile.next().trim());
    }

    textFile.close();

    for (String str : dictionary) {
        System.out.print(str + " ");
    }

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are recreating the hashset:

```
Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();
```

each time you read a new file.

If you want to keep the changes you can declare the set on higher scope perhaps making it a property in the object which is created once when the object is created, and is just filled with consequent reads of files.

Here is a sample code:

```
public class DictClass {

    private  Set<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();

    //... cunstructors, getters, setters

    void readFile(String fileName) {
        try {
            Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

            while (textFile.hasNext()) {
                // now dictionary is not recreated each time
                dictionary.add(textFile.next().trim());
            }

            textFile.close();

            for (String str : dictionary) {
                System.out.print(str + " ");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are constructors, getters and setters really necessary? (currently learning java, hence the questions).

Comment: Not obligatory. It depends on your needs. If you need to  read / write/ modify the inner state of the class, you should do it through getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

class

```
public class TextFileReader {

        private Set<String> dictionary;

        public TextFileReader(Set<String> dictionary) {
            this.dictionary = dictionary;
        }

        public void printDict(Set<String> dictionary) {
            for (String dictionary1 : dictionary) {
                System.out.println(dictionary1);
            }
        }

        public void fileScanner(String textFileName) {
            try {
                Scanner textFile = new Scanner(new File(textFileName));

                while (textFile.hasNext()) {
                    dictionary.add(textFile.next().trim());
                }

                textFile.close();

                for (String str : dictionary) {
                    System.out.print(str + " ");
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

to test

```
public class Test {

    static void main(String[] args){

        Set<String> dict = new HashSet<String>();

        TextFileReader reader = new TextFileReader(dict);

        List<String> textFileList = Arrays.asList("textFile1", "textFile2");

        for (String textFileList1 : textFileList) {
            reader.fileScanner(textFileList1);
        }

        reader.printDict(dict);

    }

}
```

to run

```
$ javac Test.java 
$ java Test
```